# what is preventing PHP from connecting to my MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, bitnami

[Updated below]

I am having a problem connecting to a MySQL database using a Bitnami LAMP stack. This is the code I used to connect on the shared-hosting server where I originally hosted the database:

```
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'username');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'database');

if ($dbc = mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)) { // Make the connnection.

    if (!mysql_select_db (DB_NAME)) { // If it can't select the database.

        // Handle the error.
        trigger_error("Could not select the database!\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());

        exit();

    } // End of mysql_select_db IF.

} else { // If it couldn't connect to MySQL.

    trigger_error("Could not connect to MySQL!\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
    exit();

} // End of $dbc IF.
```

Running this on my Bitnami server, I get no response (not even an error message). (PHP is working fine.)

I then tried

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

and got

```
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

this username/password combination definitely exists and (as far as I can tell) has access to the database in question. I am wondering what I am doing wrong and why the original script does not produce an error (or connect).

**Update:**

I followed Michael's suggestion below, and was able to connect. I wanted to reproduce the issue so I deleted that user then created a user testuser via

```
CREATE USER 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  '***';

GRANT SELECT , 
INSERT ,

UPDATE ,
DELETE ,
FILE ON * . * TO  'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  '***' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;
```

Then following Michael's suggestion, I executed

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test . * TO testuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY  'password'
```

but again I am getting

```
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

(This doesn't work whether I use '%' or 'localhost')

this is what the privileges look like for testuser in phpmyadmin

```
Database    Privileges  Grant   Table-specific privileges
test     ALL PRIVILEGES No  No   Edit Privileges
```

Comment: The username for your database is `username`?

Comment: If it doesn't produce an error on the hosted server, it's likely because `display_errors` is turned off in php.ini.

Comment: Is the host correct? If so, does substituting `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` work? Usually it is the same, but it forces the connect to use the TCP connection instead of possible local sockets, and circumvents misconfigured servers where 'localhost' is broken (yes, I have seen those...)

Comment: create another user name and give it access to the database and then give a try.

Comment: What's in your web server's error log?

Comment: @Wrikken it looks like the host is correct, I added an update at the bottom of the question

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter I tried that without success

Comment: @Crontab it just reports the same error, as in `PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/mysql_test.php on line 12
[Thu Jan 26 20:07:47 2012]

Comment: print out all the fields before mysql_connect, what is feed to the mysql_connect

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter I'm afraid I don't understand what is meant by 'feed'. I am using only the 8-line script posted above to connect with mysql_connect. If you can elaborate on what I should provide that would be great.

Comment: print the variables DB_USER, DB_HOST, etc on the screen using `echo` function and see what values are actually passed to the  `mysql_connect` function. It could be that the values are wrong.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter I am calling `mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');` using hard-coded strings (as in the second script above), so it seems like that should not be an issue, unless I am mistaken. Sorry if I am misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message received is clear - the user you're connecting with does not have access via the password you are using.  You'll need to grant privileges accordingly:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on dbname.* to username@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';
```

Comment: strangely the first time I tried this suggestion it worked, then I tried creating a new user to reproduce the problem, and now I can't get it to work. I posted exactly what I did as an update at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @jela According to what you posted, you have spaces where there should be none: `test . *` should have no spaces `test.*`

Comment: for some reason phpMyAdmin adds spaces when re-displaying the query. They were not there originally. (I re-executed the query to be sure, and still get `Could not connect: Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 0):

Try it, if you user has not password:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username');
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Make sure you are using what your shared hosting providers MySQL host path should be.  I know for GoDaddy, it is something like DBNAME.db.123456.hostedresource.com.  It will be different for yours I am sure.  localhost is probably not it.
2. Make sure that any php file you are using for your connection (where you type in your DB credentials) is OUTSIDE of the webroot.  This is a big security risk if you put this file inside your web root directory or below.  If PHP crashes on the server for whatever reason, the file WILL be rendered out to the browser for anyone to see.

Comment: I think the host is actually localhost, because I did get 'Connected Successfully' after trying Michael's suggestion. However, on deleting and recreating the user I cannot reproduce that success.

Answer (score 0):

Try

username: 'root'

password: '' (i.e. Without a password)

Comment: gives `Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`