# Access denied for user 'db_name'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have created a site that is working fine on localhost, but when i uploaded it on server its giving me the following error message.

```
Access denied for user 'azher94_ivsapps'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

There are my setting for database connection

```
    $database=          "db_name";
    $server =           "";
    $username=          "db_username";
    $password=          "db_password";



    if(mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) && mysql_select_db($database))
    //if( mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password , $database) )

    {
        echo "connected";
    }

else

{
 echo mysql_error();
}
```

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: your question title is different from the question!

Comment: [These warning means Your password is incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025182/what-is-preventing-php-from-connecting-to-my-mysql-database)

Comment: What is it about these _Access Denied_ messages that people don't understand? Surely the message is clear?

Comment: Not sure how you moved the database for your site, but seams like you need to check the permissions and/or password for 'azher94_ivsapps'@'localhost' in the MySQL database.

Comment: Please google properly.

Comment: check for grant privileges command for mysql.

Comment: I have already granted all privileges to this user

Answer (score 0):

For password you are using $password and after that you are using $Password with capital P. Please change it to $password.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define the localhost and one more thing you are doing wrong is you are not calling the variable properly. Use the code below

```
$database=          "db_name";
    $server =           "localhost";
    $username=          "db_username";
    $password=          "db_password";



    if(mysql_connect($server, $username, $password,$database) )
    //if( mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password , $database) )

    {
        echo "connected";
    }

else

{
 echo mysql_error();
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I have replace my code with yours, but the same error message it still there.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code it will work

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","your password");

mysqli_select_db("your_db",$con);
```

Comment: Even if this works the OP is using `mysql_*()`, not `mysqli_*()` - all of his other code will fail.

Comment: The error message is gone, but still its not fetching the data from database

Comment: @user3480644 can you place your query?

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens i hope you are not aware of the "mysqli" mysql was deprecated now

Comment: @Vamshi.goli I am well aware that `mysql_*()` is deprecated but the OP may not be and you haven't bothered to highlight the differences.

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens can i know why my vote as down i want to the reason can you please explain

Comment: @Vamshi.goli You'd have to ask the downvoter about that.